# Diffusers SDXL "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable"

Tags: python, torch, stable-diffusion

Just got access to SDXL model, looking to test it for its upcoming release... Unfortunately, the code we currently use for our service seems to not work with `stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-0.9`, and I'm not entirely sure what is different with SDXL and what I need to change.

We are using a different pipeline so we can generate previews of the images,  so its not the typical template that is provided on the SDXL model readme.
The error seems to be happening in `unet_2d_condition.py` (in diffusers lib)

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myalt\Desktop\testing image grid\main.py", line 159, in <module>
    socker_listener.generate_image()
  File "C:\Users\myalt\Desktop\testing image grid\main.py", line 154, in generate_image
    foo = self.blocking_code()
  File "C:\Users\myalt\Desktop\testing image grid\main.py", line 109, in blocking_code
    noise_pred = self.unet(latent_model_input, t,
  File "C:\Users\myalt\Desktop\testing image grid\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myalt\Desktop\testing image grid\venv\lib\site-packages\diffusers\models\unet_2d_condition.py", line 839, in forward
    if "text_embeds" not in added_cond_kwargs:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I've updated to `diffusers==0.18.2`.

Here is a example code which makes a bunch of images and puts them into a grid, using this a custom pipeline
https://hatebin.com/tqppqfsehk

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting, this looks like a bug in diffusers. `added_cond_kwargs` is specified as being optional, and the function signature explicitly defaults it to `None`. However, the subsequent code does not check for the `None` case, treating it as if it is a dictionary. It's worth filing an issue with `diffusers` if it hasn't already been reported. They can probably fix it by simply setting `added_cond_kwargs` to `{}` if it's passed as `None`.

In the meantime, you should be able to work around this by explicitly passing `added_cond_kwargs={}` to the unet function.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I'm getting this same error and it'll still throw an error because added_cond_kwargs needs to have "text_embeds" set it seems.

Comment: Same for me.  I set added_cond_kwargs={}, but that does not work for me either.

Answer (score 4):

for version `diffusers==0.20.0` using StableDiffusionXLPipeline instead StableDiffusion fix the problem

```
import torch
from diffusers import StableDiffusionXLPipeline

pipe = StableDiffusionXLPipeline.from_pretrained("stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0", torch_dtype=torch.float16, added_cond_kwargs={})
pipe = pipe.to("cuda")

prompt = "an illustration truck, wide shot, in frame, centered, hd, 8k, white solid background"
image = pipe(prompt).images[0]
image.save("geeks.jpg")
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using the StableDiffusionPipeline. Try using the StableDiffusionXLPipeline instead. This should solve your issue.

https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/v0.20.0/en/api/pipelines/stable_diffusion/stable_diffusion_xl#diffusers.StableDiffusionXLPipeline

Comment: Issue persists for both  XL and non-XL pipelines

Comment: @TedBrownlow can you share a notebook or code with your errors?

Comment: I think I was using some incompatible custom architecture. Using standard settings resolved the error for me